# Does monogame for linux support android solutions? I get an error when i try to create the solution

Tags: linux, xamarin, xamarin.android, monodevelop, monogame

I'm a beginner and i've been programming some simple games in monogame for Linux (xna). Now i would like to try to port this games to Android systems.
But when i try to create an Android solution, i get an error i can't continue.

Does Monogame for linux support android solutions?

Here is the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Project type 'MonoDroid' not found
>     at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectService.CreateProject (System.String type, MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation info, System.Xml.XmlElement projectOptions) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.ProjectDescriptor.CreateItem (MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation projectCreateInformation, System.String defaultLanguage) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.SolutionDescriptor.CreateEntry (MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation projectCreateInformation, System.String defaultLanguage) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.ProjectTemplate.CreateWorkspaceItem (MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation cInfo) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at MonoDevelop.Ide.Projects.NewProjectDialog.CreateProject () [0x00000] in :0

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

MonoDroid aka Xamarin.Android is solely available in Xamarin Studio on Windows or OS X. Linux is not a supported OS.